# Prove that $\lvert E[X]-m\rvert \le \sqrt{\text{var}\left(X\right)}$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, solution-verification

I want to prove that:

$$\lvert E[X]-m\rvert \le \sqrt{\text{var}\left(X\right)} $$

where $m$ is the median.

**My attempt:**

$$ \begin{aligned}&\lvert E[X]-m\rvert \le \sqrt{\text{var}\left(X\right)} \\ &\iff \left( \lvert E[X]-m\rvert \right)^2 \le \text{var}(X) \\ & \iff (E[X]-m)(E[X]-m)\le\text{var}(X) \\ & \iff \left( E[X] \right)^2-2mE[X]+m^2 \le \text{var}(X) \\ &\iff \left( E[X] \right)^2-2mE[X]+m^2 \le E[X^2]-(E[X])^2 \\ & \overbrace{\iff}^{m^2 \ge 0} \left( E[X] \right)^2\color{red}{-2mE[X]} \le E[X^2]-(E[X])^2 \\ &\iff ? \end{aligned}$$

How can I continue this proof? I realize that I problably have to use Jensens inequality: $$f(E[X])\le E[f(X)]$$

at some point but I am having a hard time getting rid of the red term. Since $m$ could be positive, negative or zero, I don't know how to continue.

Comment: @Henry Thanks! I am sorry but I don't get it. I understand that the inequality in your comment holds due to jensens inequality but how does that help me? Are you using jensens inequality to just get:  $(E[X]-m) \le \color{blue}{E[(X-m)^2]}$ or is the blue part another way to write $\text{var}(X)$? I know that the definition of the variance is $\text{var}(X)=E[(X-\mu)^2]$ where $\mu$ is the mean. But I have the median here so I am not sure if rewriting it like this is valid?

Comment: I had misread your $m$ as the mean.  In fact you have $\left(  E[X]-m \right)^2 \le  \left(  E[X]-\mu \right)^2 \le  E[(X-\mu)^2]$ since the median $m$ minimises the average absolute deviation

Comment: @qmd: Just as $\mathbb{E}[X]$ solves the problem $\operatorname{arg}\min_{c\in\mathbb{R}}E[(X-c)^2]$, medians solve $\operatorname{arg}\min_{c\in\mathbb{R}}E[|X-c|]$. I have posted more or less how to see this and how you can complete your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:

Medians satisfy the following property:

> If  $X\in L_1(\mathbb{P})$ and $m$ is a median for $X$ then,
> $$\mathbb{E}[|X-m|]=\inf_{c\in\mathbb{R}}\mathbb{E}[|X-c|].$$

To see this, notice that
$$
\max\{\mathbb{P}[X<m],\mathbb{P}[X>m]\}\leq\frac12
$$
Suppose $m\leq a\leq b$. A simple calculation gives
$$|X-b|-|X-a|=2(b-X)\mathbb{1}_{\{a<X\leq b\}}+
(b-a)\big(2\mathbb{1}_{\{X\leq a\}}-1\big)$$
From this, we have
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}[|X-b|]-\mathbb{E}[|X-a|]=2\mathbb{E}[(b-X);a<X\leq b]+(a-b)(1-2\mathbb{P}[X\leq a])\geq 0.
\end{align*}
Observe that $-m$ is a median for $-X$ whenever $m$ is a median for
$X$. Thus, if $b\leq a\leq m$, we have that
$\mathbb{E}[|b-X|]\geq \mathbb{E}[|a-X|]$.

---

Using this argument, if you further assume that $X\in L_2(\mathbb{P})$, then
$$|\mathbb{E}[X]-m|\leq\mathbb{E}[|X-m|]\leq \mathbb{E}|X-\mathbb{E}[X]|$$
The problem is then reduced to showing that $\mathbb{E}|X-\mathbb{E}[X]|\leq\sqrt{\operatorname{Var}(X)}$, which is easier. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to type this out. I will try to go through it and see if I can use it to solve my problem. I am quite new to this so it might take me a while.

Comment: One you understand the minimality properties of the median with respect to the $L_1$ norm, that is that the median minimizes the problem I decried above, then the rest may be easily obtained through the Cauchy-Schwarts intequality that stated that if $X$ and $Y$ are square integrable, then $E[|XY|]\leq(E[X^2])^{1/2}(E[Y^2])^{1/2}$. Substituting $X-E[X]$ for $X$ and $1$ form $Y$ will give you the desired inequality.